# Not passing in persistent object in recursive function and still getting the same outcome

Tags: python, recursion

```
def fib1(n, cache = {}):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    if n not in cache:
        cache[n] = fib1(n-1) + fib1(n-2)
    return cache[n]


def fib2(n, cache = {}):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    if n not in cache:
        cache[n] = fib2(n-1, cache) + fib2(n-2, cache)
    return cache[n]
```

Why does fib1 still work when I don't pass in cache as a parameter like I do in the second function fib2?

Comment: I think SO has multiple topics about "mutable default arguments".

Comment: As you don't pass an argument with the keyword `cache` it uses the default value (in this case your dictionary). That's why both functions work the same way because it is automatically using the same dictionary.

Comment: What happens if you replace "cache = {}" with "cache = dict()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above...

In the first version, `cache` is initialized once with an empty dict, and subsequent function calls access this single dict and modify it.

In the second version, you pass the `cache` dict around, but it's still one and the same dict.

In both versions, there's only one `cache` dict in the whole program. Even if you call the function 100 times, this will be a single one. The mutable default arguments are "sticky" like that and most of the time are bad idea.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: exactly. A MDA (=mutable def arg) is like a function's attribute. You set it once and then modify without passing it explicitly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, if it's `None` you have no means to modify it and you have to pass it around.